# Android как лаконично вставить кнопку поменять местами между двух кнопок?

Tags: java, android

Смотрите, http://prnt.sc/c7exd7, (с крестиком я уже разобрался), есть 2 кнопки, для выбора валют. Одна под другой. Как можно сделать справа кнопку или слева, типа как поменять местами, чтобы эта кнопка была маленькая лаконично вписывалась с краю,и была не сбоку одной кнопки, а посреди них.
У меня табличный слой. И я не знаю как там можно объединить ячейки, чтобы кнопку сделать посередине.

Кнопка х
Кнопка

У меня получается только так. А надо чтобы x сместился вниз и был как бы посередине кнопок

Comment: Не надо непонятных ссылок. Код выкладывайте текстом, а картинки спец тэгом так, чтобы она прямо в вопросе отображалась. Пока что у вас вопрос расплывчатый и ответить сложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cделайте саму кнопку переворота справа, высотой в две кнопки с валютами, а рисунок на ней любой, устраивающей вас, лаконичности, фон прозрачный.

[image: scrn]

прямоугольники на скриншоте - это ячейки сетки `GridLayout`

Для верстка более уместен будет `GridLayout`, который позволяет вертикальное вытягивание ячеек на несколько строк, в отличии от `TableLayout`/ [Пример верстки](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php) в `GridLayout`

Comment: Блин чувак респект) спасибо. Тоже на том сайте ищу решения, но как то упустил